# Changing the algorithm in the evening Spring java

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Good afternoon faced with a task. I have an endpoint that gives current orders for today, but there was a need for orders for the next day to be visible after 6 pm.

I see two solutions to this problem.

1. Check the time of the request each time and, depending on the time of the request, also pull out orders for tomorrow.
2. I am not familiar with the Spring Schedule, but it seems to me that you can use it to try to implement such functionality.
   I will be glad to hear your suggestions. I will be glad to see working examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a chance to modify the API signature then you could add a new argument: operation. Something like this:

```
@Get
List<Order> getOrder(...., Operation operation);

Enum Operation: CURRENT_DAY, CURRENT_DAY_AND_TOMORROW
```

OR if you want more flexibility you can add a `from` and `to` date fields:

```
@Get
List<Order> getOrder(...., Date from, Date to);
Dateformat= YYYY/MM/DD
```

Then you can check the request time on the server-side and make a decision: if the time is before 6 pm, you can ignore the `to` date, etc. Things really depend on the requirements, you have.

But please, do not forget the following if you use Date in your service: Clients can call your service from different time zones. I suggest you use GMT always on the server-side.

Spring Schedule is not for this. From the "helicopter view" Spring Scheduler can trigger the execution of a method. More details [here](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-task-scheduler).

Answer (score 2):

I don't feel like Spring task scheduling could help since the operation must be performed manually by an invoker/user. Your best shot is most likely #1: check for the current time and branch the application behaviour depending on the result.

Comment: I think so too, but it seems to me that it will be too heavy to request LocalDateTime for every request? I may be wrong. I'm just asking for a consult.

Comment: Getting the current time either via Instant or LocalDateTime is not an heavy operation by any means. If you have very strict NFRs and performance concerns you can verify those with some JMH microbenchmarks. If such concerns are verified you can try and move the current time calculation somewhere else (either client or database side), but I can't imagine big gains.